# Spring Boot PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Not Available from Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Due to organization limitations I am restricted to deployed as WAR file to Tomcat server, and we use the standard practice {applicationName}.properties gets bundled inside the WAR, and then Tomcat server has a {applicationName}-override.properties on the classpath.

I have the following bean definition to load the properties.

```
    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Resource[] resources = new Resource[2];
        resources[0] = new ClassPathResource("parameter-portal.properties");
        resources[1] = new ClassPathResource("parameter-portal-override.properties");
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(resources);
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
```

The problem is when I inject Environment into another bean none of my properties are there.

Calls like the following fail:

```
environment.getRequiredProperty("application.security.ldap.userSearchBase"
```

Shouldn't the properties from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer be available in Environment?

If I do the following it does work, but I expect the properties to be available in Environment

```
@Value("${application.security.ldap.userSearchBase}")
private String userSearchBase;
```

Note: The same thing is happening if I use PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Answer (score 2):

We use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. As I understand, property sources are loaded by this dedicated spring bean. `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is a **static** bean and we declare it as follows.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(){
  //return PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
}
```

- These static beans are created first.
- It ensures that property-sources are read before any @Configuration bean is initialized.